# How to transfer a volume between OpenStack Projects using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, openstack

I have a Snapshot of a DB in a project and I need to create a Volume from it and then transfer to another project so I can attach to an Instance there.

So far my task looks like this:

```yaml
- name: Create volume from Snapshot and Transfer
  openstack.cloud.volume:
    auth:
      project_id: "[project_where_the_snapshot_is]"
    state: present
    validade_certs: false
    display_name: "Test"
    size: 100
    snapshot_id: "[snapshot_id]"
    timeout: 900
```

Unfortunatelly, this only creates the volume, but does not transfer it. I've been googling about this for a while now and I'm not sure if this module is able to manage volume transfers.

Another option would be to write a task to run OpenStack CLI commands. But, of course, it would be better to use a module for that.

Comment: Not sure if you *must* use ansible but there's a command to do exactly that: `openstack volume transfer request create`  (or a button in the Horizon dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's no Ansible module capable of doing so. The OpenStack CLI allows you to complete [this](https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/rocky/cli/cli-manage-volumes.html) in two steps, first create a transfer request then accept it, so the the hypothetical module closest to what you are trying to achieve should be extending the [volume_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openstack/cloud/volume_info_module.html) or writing a similar module, where the module would update the volume properties with the new project ID.

Comment: That's exactly how I did it. https://gist.github.com/orpheustaken/eeb6e39a12395b792354a1466c415a83